# Weird return values to IPN since about a week ago

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We use fields called "item_name" and "item_number" in integration with PayPal to convey the details of the ordered product.

Recently I've been seeing PayPal transactions return "Shopping cart" in item_name, rather than the string that was posted to PayPal in that field.

This behavior is inconsistent, I have logs that show 5 transactions with 1, 4 and 5 having the missing item_name, and 2 and 3 having the old item_name without any issues whatsoever.

I've tried to find out whether item_name was deprecated but it appears to be still active, as per https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

We are not using shopping cart, we're using PayPal Payments Standard. Our PayPal send code is:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="PayPal">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?=$item_name; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?=$item_number; ?>">
```

The item_name and item_number can be seen at the top of the PayPal pages the user sees next.

Could someone from PayPal please explain why is there this inconsistency in the behavior, and whether it's a problem with PayPal or a forerunner of change I wasn't aware of?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Maciek

Answer (score -1):

We also starting experiencing this problem on 8/19/2017. Item_name = "Shopping Cart" Here are others reporting this problem:
https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments/item-name-changed-to-quot-Shopping-Cart-quot-in-IPN/td-p/1290682

Comment: While this post may help the OP to fix the problem, it does not provide an answer like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)